# SharePoint Online Page Unresponsive

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

Last few days I am facing this error and not find any solution related this error. 
Is there any particular scenario for getting SharePoint online "page unresponsive" error?
Below is the error image.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Try this tool and see what kind of info you get:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/page-diagnostics-for-spo

Answer (score 1):

Per my research, this error often occurs in chrome page, please change a browser to check whether the issue still exists.

If the issue only occurs in Chrome browser, please uncheck "Use hardware acceleration when available" option in system settings and compare the result.

[image]

If not, please refer Trevor's suggestion for page troubleshooting.

More information:

https://mashtips.com/fix-page-unresponsive-error-chrome/